# Custom session data not persisting in ember-fire

Tags: javascript, session, firebase, ember.js, emberfire

I am trying to add the custom session variable `session.currentUser.isBusiness` in ember-fire. However, on page reload, the data does not persist and disappears.

I'm putting the login logic within my login route, which looks like this:

```
import Ember from ‘ember’;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
 classNames: [‘login-form’],
    router: Ember.inject.service(‘-routing’),
   actions: {
   signIn(provider) {
     let controller = this;
     this.get(‘session’).open(‘firebase’, {
       provider: provider,
       email: this.get(‘email’) || ‘’,
       password: this.get(‘password’) || ‘’,
     }).then(() => {
       this.get(‘session’).set(‘currentUser.isBusiness’, true );

       controller.get(‘router’).transitionTo(‘business.portal’);
     }, (error) => {
       alert(error);
     });
   },
   googleSignIn(){
     let controller=this;
           this.get(‘session’).open(‘firebase’, { provider: ‘google’}).then(function(data) {
             data = null;
           controller.transitionToRoute(‘portal’);
           }, (error) => {
       alert(error);
     });
   }
 }
});
```

It works when I first sign in and I can see that `session.currentUser.isBusiness` is set to false; however, when the page is reloaded, `session.currentUser.isBusiness` no longer exists.

I'm using Ember 2.11 and the latest version of ember-fire.

What should I change to make sure the data persists?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store data into Firebase internal table(actually you are just setting property to session object) and it is not possible. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039334/3313851).

You can create `User` model instead:

```
// app/models/user.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  // …
  isBusiness: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

And check if you already have this user signed in or create new and set all properties if user with this `uid` was not found.

```
// component
// …
this
  .get('session')
  .open('firebase', { provider: 'google' })
  .then(() => {
    let uid = this.get('session.currentUser.uid');
    this
      .get('store')
      .findRecord('user', uid)
      .then((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return console.log(user.get('isBusiness')); // => true
        }

        this
          .get('store')
          .createRecord('user', { id: uid, isBusiness: true })
          .save()
          .then((newUser) => {
            console.log(newUser.get('isBusiness')); // => true
          });
      }); 
  });
```

Code is "abstract" so you can get idea what I mean. Please report any issues if you will find them.