# How to add username with email and password in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase and I'm trying to add a username to the database with the email and password.

[image: This is how my database look like now]

Is there a way to do it or is `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function only for email and password?

```
signUp.addEventListener("click", function(user)
{
    var username = usernameTxt.value;
    var email = emailTxt.value;
    var password = passwordTxt.value;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error)
    {


      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      if (errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use')
      {
            alert('email-already-in-use.');
        }
        else
        {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
          console.log(error);

    });
});
```

The solution that i found to how to add username with the createUserWithEmailAndPassword() function:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

  var username = usernameTxt.value;

  if (user) {
    firebaseDataBase.ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
        email: user.email,
        uid : user.uid,
        username: username
    });


    console.log("User is signed in.");
  } else {
     console.log("No user is signed in.");

  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Extra Details on Firebase User Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038611/add-extra-details-on-firebase-user-table)

Answer (score 15):

This cannot be done through `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` but there is a firebase method for this  . **You will need to listen for when authentication state is changed** , **get the user** , then **update the profile info** . See Below

This code would come after `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

                if (user) {

                   // Updates the user attributes:

                  user.updateProfile({ // <-- Update Method here

                    displayName: "NEW USER NAME",
                    photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"

                  }).then(function() {

                    // Profile updated successfully!
                    //  "NEW USER NAME"

                    var displayName = user.displayName;
                    // "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
                    var photoURL = user.photoURL;

                  }, function(error) {
                    // An error happened.
                  });     

                }
    });
```

As stated in firebase User Api here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateProfile

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there any way to ensure the displayName is unique amongst all users? Maybe by requesting the username and seeing if anything comes up first?

Answer (score 14):

You need to create that database `users` child node yourself ;-)

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function *only* creates a new user in Firebase authentication service. The database itself isn't changed at all as a result.

To add this new user to the database as well, try:

```
firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).set(...)
```

Comment: So i will need to add your code inside the firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error){} right ?

Comment: Yes! Do it once the promise returns.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `users` endpoint and store custom user data in there.

```
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl,
    // Add more stuff here
  });
}
```

Have a look to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 2):

Firebase auth v9 has changed how user profile is updated. This way is very helpful if the only things you want to manage are `displayName` and `photoUrl` and want to avoid creating separate database.

```
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile
} from 'firebase/auth';

const auth = getAuth();
...some code...
     createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, body.email, body.password)
        .then(({ user }) => {
          updateProfile(user, { displayName: formData.name });
        })
        .catch(console.log)
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
          setAuthenticating(false);
        });
// OR
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, body.email, body.password)
        .then(({ user }) => {
          updateProfile(user, { displayName: newDisplayName });
        })
        .catch(console.log)
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
          setAuthenticating(false);
        });
// OR
    onIdTokenChanged(auth, user => {
      updateProfile(user, { displayName: newDisplayName });
      setAuthenticating(false);
    });
...some code...
```

Reference - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users