# Firebase Authentication with FullName

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to register user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword function, which logically receives only email and password. But I want also to write fullname field of user. Can you tell me what is the way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: Then take the name as an input from the registeration.

Comment: @Rafee firebase doesn't allow to create custom fields when registration but there must be some trick to do it

Comment: Trying console your user after registeration. you can see details `user.displayName`

Comment: In place of passing username and password fields, pass full name and password as arguments.

Comment: @BadriPaudel I mean where? I use createUserWithEmailAndPassword. It only accepts email and password. But where to pass fullName. Thats what I am here for

Comment: You cannot add additional fields with reateUserWithEmailAndPassword. to do it, you have to create a User table in your database, listen when authentication changes and update user with provided username. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509021/how-to-add-username-with-email-and-password-in-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want also to write fullname field of user.

I make the assumption that you want to update the `displayName` property of the [`user`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) Object.

Do as follows, by using the [`updateProfile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile) method:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
    return user.updateProfile({displayName: "Your name"});
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Profile updated successfully!");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```