# Adding additional information to a Firebase when user sign up with email and password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to add additional information to a Firebase user object, like

- Phone Number
- Username
- Address
- etc...

How can i add extra information in user profile details when user sign up `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` this method

My firebase version is -
"firebase": "^5.7.2"

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible. It is suggested that additional details be stored manually in Real Time Database or Firestore. Link to a similar discussion.

[Add Extra Details on Firebase User Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038611/add-extra-details-on-firebase-user-table)

Thanks,
Dinakaran

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can only add username or photo URI with this method:

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName(username)
            .setPhotoUri("uri")
            .build();

    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });
```